# Count the number of broken links on a page

Tags: javascript, ajax, for-loop

I wrote a JavaScript to detect the broken links on a page.  If there are 10 broken links, I want to count the broken links and alert only one time instead of 10 times. How can I tweak my code to meet my requirement.

```
function doCheck(i,href) {
jQuery.ajax({
    url: href,
    method: "HEAD",
    statusCode: {
        404: function () {
          x ++;
          alert(x +'broken link found');
          anchors[i].style.border='2px dotted red';
        },
        200: function() {
          anchors[i].style.border='2px dotted green';
    }
    }
});
}


var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var x = 0;
for (var i=0; i<anchors.length; i++) {
var href = anchors[i].getAttribute('href');
doCheck(i,href);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on AvcS response.

You need to use a global variable to save the count of a broken link, and when your code found any 404 increase this global variable and after the loop, you can show the counter with an alert or put the value into the field

Answer (score 2):

This will do what you are asking for. Let your x counter count and when  your loop is on the last anchor; then it will alert with count of broken link.

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var x = 0;
for (var i=0; i<anchors.length; i++) {
var href = anchors[i].getAttribute('href');
doCheck(i,href,anchors[i]);
If ( i === anchors.length - 1  ) { 
  SetTimeout( function() {
   alert(x +' broken link found');
   }, 4000);

}
}

function doCheck(i,href, current_el) {
jQuery.ajax({
url: href,
method: "HEAD",
statusCode: {
    404: function () {
      x++;
      console.log(x);
      current_el.style.border='2px dotted red';
    },
    200: function() {
      current_el.style.border='2px dotted green';
     }
} 
});
}
```

Comment: var x always return 0.

Comment: Do a console.log in the 404 function that prints the x variable. If it prints the count then it just means that your alert above is happening too fast. Just wrap your alert above with a setTimeout function and set it to like a 4000 timeout. That should give enough time for the ajax requests to come back. Or it may need a little more time than 4 sec. Have to test it.

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of requests have been completed, if the number of completed requests is equal to number of requests sent, then all your anchors have been handled, you can alert then

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var x = 0; var y = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    var href = anchors[i].getAttribute('href');
    doCheck(i,href);
}

function doCheck(i,href) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: href,
    method: "HEAD",
    statusCode: {
      404: function () {
        x++;
        anchors[i].style.border='2px dotted red';
      },
      200: function() {
        anchors[i].style.border='2px dotted green';
      }
    }
  }).complete(function () {
    if (y++ === anchors.length) {
      alert(x +'broken link found');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: It doesn't alert anything @AvcS